# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused in Hadoop while using shell commands

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

I have installed  7 VM instances running Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS. instance-1(hostname) runs namenode and several other services while all other instances run datanode services. I wanted to create a directory on one datanode's hdfs root directory but I am getting this error

```
root@instance-2:~# hdfs dfs -mkdir hdfs://localhost/user/
mkdir: Call From instance-2/10.240.17.255 to localhost:8020 failed on
connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For 
more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
root@instance-2:~# hdfs dfs -mkdir hdfs://instance-2/user/
mkdir: Call From instance-2/10.240.17.255 to instance-2:8020 failed on
connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For 
more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

this is my jps output on instance-2

```
root@instance-2:~# jps
2267 NodeManager
5012 Jps
2274 DataNode
```

this my jps output on instance-1

```
root@instance-1:~# jps
9043 Jps
1490 Main
3011 RunJar
3227 ResourceManager
4736 HeadlampServer
2409 SecondaryNameNode
3095 JobHistoryServer
2411 QuorumPeerMain
2734 AlertPublisher
2423 RunJar
2562 Bootstrap
5059 Main
2430 Bootstrap
5174 EventCatcherService
5060 Main
2487 NameNode
```

I tried to create the directory from instance-1 still I am getting the same error

```
root@instance-1:~# hdfs dfs -mkdir hdfs://instance-2/user/
mkdir: Call From instance-1/10.240.71.132 to instance-2:8020 failed on 
connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For 
more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

this is my hosts file of instance-1

```
root@instance-1:~# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.240.71.132 instance-1
10.240.17.255 instance-2
10.240.50.197 instance-3
10.240.61.121 instance-4
10.240.98.215 instance-5
10.240.72.7 instance-6
10.240.216.72 instance-7
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal metadata
```

this is my hosts file of instance-2

```
root@instance-2:~# cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost
10.240.71.132 instance-1
10.240.17.255 instance-2
10.240.50.197 instance-3
10.240.61.121 instance-4
10.240.98.215 instance-5
10.240.72.7 instance-6
10.240.216.72 instance-7
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal metadata
```

Here is the telnet command output

```
root@instance-2:~# telnet localhost 8020
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

root@instance-2:~# telnet instance-2 8020
Trying 10.240.17.255...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

netstat command on instance-1 shows nothing running on port 8020

```
root@instance-1:~# netstat -tulpn | grep 8020
root@instance-1:~# netstat -tulpn | grep 8020
root@instance-1:~# netstat -tulpn | grep 8020
```

Hope this info helps you to look into the issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing is listening at the IP:port you're trying to connect to. The fact that you're trying to create a directory via this connection is irrelevant.

Comment: The telnet and netstat outputs confirm that.

Comment: In my core-site.xml the fs.defaultfs property is set to hdfs://instance-1:8020.

Comment: So you've configured it but it still isn't running.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the firewall for your Ubuntu VM. This link will help to [disable the firewall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/250775/how-do-i-turn-off-the-firewall-in-ubuntu-12-04). Otherwise you can also add [exception to the firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW).

Based on the cloud provider you have the open the ports of your virtual machines. If you are using [AMS EC2](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html) open the required port numbers for your VM's in security groups.. 
If you are using [Microsoft Azure](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/) add required endpoints.

After adding the exception restart your hadoop services from namenode. Hope everything will work fine.